# Jade template won't output right html when using href

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I'm having the following problem when using this jade template:

```
p
  a(href="https://{{ provider }}.com/{{ nickname }}")(target='_blank') {{ nickname }}
  | {{> chat_box_text }}
```

It outputs the following html:

```
<p><a href="<a href=" https:="" twitter.com="" mateusgff"="" target="_blank">https://twitter.com/mateusgff</a>" target="_blank">mateusgfftesting<span class="date">4:41 PM</span></p>
```

If I use **#** instead of **https://{{ provider }}.com/{{ nickname }}** it works great. Why is that happening?

Comment: When i run this on my own, it comes out fine. Do you have anything else messing with Express views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
p
  a(href='https://{{ provider }}.com/{{ nickname }}', target='_blank') {{ nickname }}
  | {{> chat_box_text }}
```

I believe you shouldn't have double quotations where you have them but singular ones, e.g. '